# Is there database of orphaned blocks?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, blockchain.info, block

Is there database of orphaned blocks?

https://blockchain.info/orphaned-blocks does not work right now

Does anybody keep them?

Also I am looking for those transactions which were not included in blocks (non-standard, double-spends, not enough fees, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need a user interface or to find them via API? We do not have UI at the moment for this (we will very soon) but you can definitely use our [REST API](https://support.biteasy.com/kb/rest-api) to get them.

If the API is what you need then you can just use the following API call to filter ORPHANED blocks only.

> https://api.biteasy.com/blockchain/v1/blocks?type=ORPHANED

If the transactions weren't included in the main chain then they will either be DEAD or PENDING and you can fetch them with the following API call:

> https://api.biteasy.com/blockchain/v1/transactions?confidence=DEAD

and

> https://api.biteasy.com/blockchain/v1/transactions?confidence=PENDING

Check out the link to our documentation and also you can use our testing tool which you can find here https://www.biteasy.com/developers/sandbox

Answer (score 1):

In this: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1403.6676.pdf paper Christian Decker and Roger Wattenhofer describe their use of a system to monitor the bitcoin network for failed transactions.

Some tools are available on https://github.com/cdecker?tab=repositories .

Though not a database by itself, these tools might be useful for building such a database.

Comment: Thank you. I already have a tool, which saves all transactions and all blocks received from my peers. Unfortunately, I have to keep it online and connected 24/7 what is quite difficult for me. And I have to choose well-connected nodes to connect ( https://blockchain.info/hub-nodes also is broken ). This tool sniffes current network activity, but first of all i am interested in "bitcoin archeology" - those transactions which were in past but not accesseble now through the blochchain